# nextSibling & previousSibling in YUI

Tags: javascript, yui

Is there any way to get nextSibling and previousSibling of an element in YUI3? Just like there is :

```
node.get('parentNode');
```

where node is some node in the DOM.

Comment: Did you try node.get('nextSibling') ?

Answer (score 4):

You want .next() and .previous()

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Node.html#method_next
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Node.html#method_previous

Comment: They're not equivalent to the `nextSibling` and `previousSibling` properties of a DOM node though, since they only consider elements and ignore other types of node such as text nodes.

Comment: Correct, but IMO they're much more useful in most of the cases where you'd want next/prev sibling. His comment on your answer also indicate that he doesn't want text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation suggests that `node.get("nextSibling")` and `node.get("previousSibling")` are what you need.

Comment: I always get a null for it even though there exists a next subling

Comment: I double checked it. It shows the text as next sibling of an li tag. eg: <li id="first">text1</li><li id="second">text2</li>

Comment: @Vids: That may well be correct. If there is whitespace between the `<li>` elements in your HTML, there will be a text node containing that whitespace between the two `<li>`s.